# What is the syntax and semantics of the `where` keyword?

Tags: rust, syntax

Unfortunately, Rust's documentation regarding `where` is very lacking. The keyword only appears in one or two unrelated examples in the reference.

1. What semantic difference does `where` make in the following code? Is there any difference at all? Which form is preferred?

   ```
   fn double_a<T>(a: T) -> T where T: std::num::Int {
       a + a
   }

   fn double_b<T: std::num::Int>(a: T) -> T {
       a + a
   }
   ```
2. In the implementation of the CharEq trait, it seems that `where` is being used as some sort of "selector" to implement Trait for anything that matches some closure type. Am I correct?

Is there any way I can get a better, more complete picture of `where`? (full specification of usage and syntax)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In your example, the two codes are strictly equivalent.

The `where` clauses were introduced to allow more expressive bound-checking, doing for example :

```
fn foo<T>(a: T) where Bar<T>: MyTrait { /* ... */ }
```

Which is not possible using only the old syntax.

Using `where` rather than the original syntax is generally preferred for readability even if the old syntax can still be used.

You can imagine for example constructions like

```
fn foo<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C)
    where A: SomeTrait + OtherTrait,
          B: ThirdTrait<A>+ OtherTrait,
          C: LastTrait<A, B>
{
    /* stuff here */
}
```

which are much more readable this way, even if the could still be expressed using the old syntax.

For your question about the `CharEq` trait, the code is:

```
impl<F> CharEq for F where F: FnMut(char) -> bool {
    #[inline]
    fn matches(&mut self, c: char) -> bool { (*self)(c) }

    #[inline]
    fn only_ascii(&self) -> bool { false }
}
```

It literally means: Implementation of trait `CharEq` for all type `F` that already implements the trait `FnMut(char) -> bool` (that is, a closure or a function taking a `char` and returning a `bool`).

For more details, you can look at the RFC that introduced the `where` clauses : https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/135

Comment: also the reason both trait bounds and where clauses exist is that  nikomatsakis "decided against this both to avoid breaking lots of existing code and because the existing syntax is convenient much of the time." The latter part conflicts with "is generally preferred", do you have any sources on that preference/coding style?

Comment: Sources... No I don't. I mainly assumed it from seeing where clauses used pretty much everywhere I looked.

Comment: Just to vent a bit, this answer is literally the only place you'll learn that multiple where clauses are comma-separated! The official book, the official language reference, and rust by example are all quiet on this and provide only examples with a single bound! As a result it's easy to end up stuck googling until you find a stack overflow answer related to what you are looking for.