# Is there something like expression templates in Rust?

Tags: c++, rust

In C++, expression templates is a technique that relies on the compiler's knowledge about expressions in C++ code to simplify them and optimize them beyond what would be possible in a procedural program. It's a powerful technique used by e.g. the Eigen and Armadillo matrix libraries to speed up certain compound operations on matrices. An [incomplete wiki page on the Eigen web page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Expression_templates) almost starts explaining it.

I wonder if a similar technique exists in Rust, i.e. is there a way to make the Rust compiler optimize certain expressions at compile time so that the least amount of temporaries is created.

Comment: afaik rustc doesn't do any optimizations except for constant evaluation (fold expressions that only depend on constants). All the optimizations are done in llvm.

Comment: @ker Yes, but that is mostly an implementation detail, irrelevant for run time performance, as LLVM is really good at optimizations.

Comment: @ker yes, but it is due to how templates are instantiated that the compiler/optimizer actually has enough information to readily optimize these things, so I guess the language or rustc itself needs to have some way of doing this kind of operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read [Expression Templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) right, then you can see them in action with Rust Iterators: methods such as [filter](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), [take](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take), etc etc return an expression template, a struct which represents the computation but doesn't perform it until requested. This gives the optimization you require right away, no temporaries are created.

Using the [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405621/what-is-the-syntax-and-semantics-of-the-where-keyword) clause I imagine one can write specializations to further optimize certain combinations of computations.

Comment: The main thing lacking (but coming soon hopefully) are dependent types in rust. e.g. `template<int i>` has no rust equivalent, so things like loop unrolling are up to LLVM to figure out, whereas expression templates in C++ can (essentially) guarantee it.